# How to replace values in a column of dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I would like to replace textual data with numerical data.

I'm ingesting the data like this:

```
> credit_arff <- read.arff("/Users/birdy/credit-g.arff")

> factor(table(credit_arff$checking_status))
         <0       >=200    0<=X<200 no checking 
        274          63         269         394
```

I would like to replace all `<0` values with `-1`

Here is how the data looks like in `View`

[image]

After the replace the number of `<0` should remain same (i.e. `274`)

Comment: It's already a factor. What do you want to accomplish by changing the values to "-1"? Would just renaming the level work? `levels(credit_arff$checking_status)[1]<-"-1"` assuming `class(credit_arff$checking_status)` is already a "factor". Since it's just a label, "-1" isn't really any different than "<0" in any meaningful way.

Comment: My aim is to be able to draw histograms. I can't do that when the data is textual. Eventually, I want to replace all textual data. i.e. `<0` would turn to `-1`...`no checking` would be `0` etc.

Comment: `hist(credit_arff$checking_status)` doesn't work but `hist(credit_arff$duration)` does because `duration` is all numeric. This data is already available in "numeric" but it makes no sense as there is no mapping of what the numbers represent: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/german.data-numeric

Comment: How did `hist()` get involved with all of this. `hist()` is meant for observations of continuous random variables. It clearly sounds like `credit_arff$checking_status` is already discrete. I don't understand what the link you provided is supposed to show. Are you saying that's the raw data? But something must have already transformed it to values like `0<=X<200`; neither `table()` nor `factor()` will do that on their own. Perhaps this is unique to `aarf` files which I admit I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the raw data from "<0" to "-1" before you tabulate it with:

```
credit_arff$checking_status[ credit_arff$checking_status=="<0" ] <- "-1"
```

Or you can tabulate it first and then get the headings with

```
rownames(table(credit_arff$checking_status)
```

...and change it there if you want.  The limiting factor is that the vector of data, or the vector of rownames, will not contain a mix of numeric and character data.  Even if you omit the doublequotes around "-1" from the code above, the data will change to "-1".  Whether that's acceptable depends what you're doing with the numbers next.  Or will you be changing all the other contents to numeric as well?

Comment: doing that changes the value of <0 retrieved by factor(table(credit_arff$checking_status))

Comment: You mean it changes the *count* of "<0"?  I can't see why.  Maybe come up with a smaller example that we can copy-paste to replicate the problem.